# Laravel Vite issue when runing npm run dev

Tags: php, laravel, npm, vite, laravel-vite

I'm using Laravel 9. When I try to run `npm install`, then run `npm run dev`, the error below shows up.

```
VITE v3.0.9  ready in 648 ms

  ➜  Local:   http://127.0.0.1:5173/
  ➜  Network: use --host to expose

  LARAVEL v9.26.0  plugin v0.5.4

  ➜  APP_URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000
C:\Software Project\Web Development\AdminPanel\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1356
        return callback(new Error(error), null);
                        ^

Error: The service was stopped: write EPIPE
    at C:\Software Project\Web Development\AdminPanel\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1356:25    
    at C:\Software Project\Web Development\AdminPanel\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:678:9      
    at afterClose (C:\Software Project\Web Development\AdminPanel\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:656:7)
    at C:\Software Project\Web Development\AdminPanel\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:2075:11    
    at onwriteError (node:internal/streams/writable:417:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:85:21)
```

Comment: What version of esbuild are you using in your package.json?

Comment: the version im using is "0.14.54"

Comment: Perhaps try to upgrade the package: npm install esbuild@latest

Comment: $ npm run dev

> dev
> vite

failed to load config from C:\Software Project\Web Development\AdminPanel\vite.config.js
error when starting dev server:
ReferenceError: os is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Software Project\Web .......

Comment: Try adding the following to the top of your vite.config.js: import os from 'os';

Comment: this is what i get :  https://postimg.cc/gL6ZK3sF

Comment: Not sure how to help you besides removing /node_modules directory and running npm install again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247535/discussion-between-kwenziwa-lizwi-khanyile-and-karl-hill).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem appeared with versions above `9.0`

Download a `new Laravel project`

Type the following command and your problem will be solved

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel example-app 9.0
```

The following commands will work successfully
`npm install`,  and `npm run dev`